# Once you got the Authorization Code from Step 1 click the Exchange authorization code

Tags: google-oauth

I am not sure why i am getting this error message. i have inserted the ids

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 322
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground
```

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 68
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Sun, 11 Nov 2018 23:59:34 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

```
{
  "error_description": "Bad Request", 
  "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

Comment: please edit your question to explain the steps you have taken to get to the moment you see this error.

Comment: Include the data in the HTTP body section. As the error states your `grant` request is not valid. `grant_type` will look like `grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` or `grant_type: refresh_token` before encoding. The first is for requesting an access token the second for renewing an existing access token with a refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Bad Request error occurs when the request syntax are wrong (i.e. when a parameter or a header you are supposed to send is missing or contains an incorrect/invalid value). Best option is to check [OAuth Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) are figure out what you have done wrong in the token request. Google might have a slightly different implementation from the actual specification, but I think it won't be difficult to find the issue after checking the documentation.

Access token request specification for authorization code grant can be found [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3).